# How to update UIProgressView correctly in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, updates, uiprogressview

I've got class `LoadViewController` and on start i call this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    NSData *dataOfURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kRSSURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:dataOfURL waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
```

Where `kbgQueue` is

```
   #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

On main thread is executed `fetchedData:`.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
parser.delegate = self;

if ([parser parse]) {

    // if parsed.
    if (!data) {

        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else {

        [data removeAllObjects];
    }

    data = [parser getParsedData];

    ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    viewController.array = data;

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
    //[self reloadData];
}
else {

    NSLog(@"False.");
}

}
```

As you see i use my own `XMLParser` helper class, where i fetch all data.When one piece of data is downloaded i call `[self.delegate passProgress:fetchedItems/20.0f];` by delegate and in `LoadViewController` is something like this:

```
-(void)passProgress:(float)progress {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.progressView setProgress:progress];
    NSLog(@"Updated!");
});
}
```

But the problem is: progressView isn't updated after download one piece of 20 data items. Where is the problem?

Comment: When downloading data it is better to use `NSURLConnection` because then you can handle incomming bytes and update the progress to show really percentage of data donwloaded, have a look at the great [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: @rckoenes - thank you. i'll check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is it correctly but i changed in `LoadViewController` from `perfromOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to `perfromInBackground:withObject:`, but it works.